# How can I handle asynchronous functions called in a loop?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to understand how to get a for loop to wait for a function to complete before moving on to the next iteration. I think I want to use a callback, but I'm unsure how to go about it. In my example, I'd like for the loop to wait for the `setTimeout` so that the numbers in the array are displayed in the proper order:

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3];
$('#myButton').on('click',function1);

function function1() {
 for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
   function2(myArr[i]);
  }
}

function function2(number) {
 if(number == 2) {
   setTimeout(function(){$('#myDiv').append('<div>'+number+'</div>');},1000);
  } else {
   $('#myDiv').append('<div>'+number+'</div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">test</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Promise and async/await to achieve this. Return a promise from `function2()` and if the condition is met resolve the Promise after some time else resolve it immediately. Here's a working example:

```js
async function function1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    await function2(myArr[i]);
  }
}

function function2(number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (number == 2) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#myDiv').append('<div>' + number + '</div>');
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#myDiv').append('<div>' + number + '</div>');
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```